# How do I sync iCloud Drive between 2 MacBooks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, finder, catalina

I am switching to a new MacBook, and all my files are in my iCloud Desktop and Documents folders. All my files are accessible on icloud.com through a browser, but not in the finder on my new MacBook. All my other iCloud files are available, my photos have synced and all other iCloud directories show up and have the cloud with a download arrow. The Desktop and Documents folders have a dotted outline of the cloud, when hovered over says "waiting to upload".

I have made sure my settings are set to use iCloud Drive for these directories, I've tried resetting everything and signing out and back in. I have let my laptop sit for a week now, but there is no hint of even trying to sync to iCloud Drive for Desktop and Documents. Does anyone know how I can get my files to download? Or at least visible to manually download through the finder? Im running OS X 10.15.6